# How can I create this XML in .Net?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmldocument, xmlwriter

I need to serialise an object to the following XML in .Net.

Probably the easiest way is to implement IXMLSerializable due to the control I need over the end result.... What do I need to do to output in the following schema:

```
<ns2:ProcessRepairOrder languageCode="de-DE" releaseID="1.0" systemEnvironmentCode="PROD" versionID="1.0">
    <ns2:ApplicationArea>
       <ns2:Sender>
          <ns2:CreatorNameCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:TextType">SomeVendor</ns2:CreatorNameCode>
          <ns2:SenderNameCode name="Dave"/>
       <ns2:Sender>
    </ns2:ApplicationArea>
</ns2:ProcessRepairOrder>
```

More specifically it is the prefixes without the namespace, and the xsi:type I can't get into the XML.

the full version looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns1:PutMessage xmlns:ns1="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport" xmlns:ns2="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" xmlns:ns3="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9">
      <ns1:payload>
        <ns1:content>
          <ns2:ProcessRepairOrder languageCode="de-DE" releaseID="1.0" systemEnvironmentCode="PROD" versionID="1.0">
          ...many more XML elements
      </ns2:ProcessRepairOrder>
    </ns1:PutMessage>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Everything I can think of - this includes implementing IXMLSerializable and using XMLDocument inside. I don't know how to produce the above. I can paste examples, but they will just clutter the question as I have about 50 lines of code that don't produce what is required...

Comment: What happened when you implemented IXMLSerializable and what about it was not satisfactory?

Comment: Did you try feeding you *.xsd files into xsd.exe, generating a class and using it for serialization?

Comment: @AVIDeveloper we have not been provided with xsd files.

Comment: @TomW It wasn't satisfactory as I couldn't get it to produce the same XML. The link to XML answer below looks like the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use .NET 3.5? If so LINQ-to-XML might be easier to use. Here is some code I've tested which will produce exactly the XML output in your question:

```cs
XNamespace ns2 = "some-uri";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

XElement root = new XElement("Root",
    // Define ns2 namespace on Root element
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns2", ns2.NamespaceName),
    new XElement(ns2 + "ProcessRepairOrder",
        // Attributes of ProcessRepairOrder
        new XAttribute("languageCode", "de-DE"),
        new XAttribute("releaseID", "1.0"),
        new XAttribute("systemEnvironmentCode", "PROD"),
        new XAttribute("versionID", "1.0"),
        // Child elements of ProcessRepairOrder
        new XElement(ns2 + "ApplicationArea",
            new XElement(ns2 + "Sender",
                new XElement(ns2 + "CreatorNameCode",
                    // Attributes of CreatorNameCode and define xsi namespace
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
                    new XAttribute(xsi + "type", "ns3:TextType"),
                    // Value of CreatorNameCode,
                    "SomeVendor"
                ),
                new XElement(ns2 + "SenderNameCode",
                    // Attributes of SenderNameCode
                    new XAttribute("name", "Dave")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You can look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387068.aspx) to see how to create XML tress using LINQ-to-XML, and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) explains how to apply XML namespaces to them.

**Edited:**

Following on from your comments below, it seems you want a less standard approach in that you can't have the root element I've defined above, but LINQ-to-XML seems to require it in order to create a valid XML structure with the correct namespaces defined. If you want to use this approach then there is a way around it but it requires a bit more fiddling around with the output.

Using the code I've written above and then doing `root.Elements().First().ToString()` would produce this serialized XML:

```
<ns2:ProcessRepairOrder languageCode="de-DE" releaseID="1.0" systemEnvironmentCode="PROD" versionID="1.0" xmlns:ns2="some-uri">
  <ns2:ApplicationArea>
    <ns2:Sender>
      <ns2:CreatorNameCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:TextType">SomeVendor</ns2:CreatorNameCode>
      <ns2:SenderNameCode name="Dave" />
    </ns2:Sender>
  </ns2:ApplicationArea>
</ns2:ProcessRepairOrder>
```

Nearly there but notice that LINQ-to-XML has inserted the `xmlns:ns2` namespace on the `ProcessRepairOrder` because to use `ns2` elements throughout the hierarchy it needs to be defined somewhere. But now that you have this in a string format you can easily use `String.Replace()` to remove that and you'll end up with what you require.

I wouldn't say it is an elegant solution, but it would work for your non-standard method of producing XML.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll create a test to see.

Comment: You've added a root element, which isn't allowed - the root element needs to be '<ns2:ProcessRepairOrder'. I can see why you have done it, as you can't seem to add the ns2: bit to the root element? I'm beginning to think I'm going to have to just build a string :(

Comment: I can see some similar examples on one of the links - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx, but I need to create <aw:Root> instead of <aw:Root xmlns:aw="http://www.adventure-works.com">

Comment: That doesn't sound like standard XML - surely you would have to define the namespace of `ns2` somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, its a headache to be honest - I've updated the question to include the rest of the XML surrounding the bit I posted already. I can't create the service proxy code yet, the service won't build, but basically there is a content object that I need to put xml into. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Looking at the additions you've added to your question, do you mean that something else is generating the XML down to `ns1:content` and you need to insert something else into this inner XML?

Comment: At the moment that is the way it looks.

Comment: Have edited my answer in response to your comments, hope it meets your requirements

Comment: I think your solution fits. Your right - trust IBM to come up with a non-standard standard ;)